# SQL Server: Get hour of year from datetime

Tags: sql-server, datetime

In SQL Server, I would like to get the hour of the year (from 1 to 8760) from a datetime value. Any idea how to achieve this? Thanks a lot!

Example (datetime is in format yyyy-mm-dd-hh-mm-ss)

```
Input: datetime => Output: hour_of_year
----------------------------------------
2015-01-01 01:00:00 =>    1
2015-01-01 02:00:00 =>    2
2015-01-02 01:00:00 =>   25
2015-02-15 08:00:00 => 1088
2015-12-31 22:00:00 => 8758
2015-12-31 23:00:00 => 8759
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `DATEPART`:

```
SELECT DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR,GETDATE())*24 + DATEPART(HOUR,GETDATE())
```

Comment: Thanks so much, Lamak!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATEDIFF ( hour, DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,GETDATE()), 0), GETDATE())
```